# Firestore security rules always fail first evaluation and then succeed for second

Tags: reactjs, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a React JS app that uses Firestore Web SDK (modular). The security rules (see below) always fail the first evaluation and succeed in the second.

Both evaluations show sequentially in the debugger and happen almost at the same time. But the DB operation is called from the code only once. This happens for most collections in the DB.

Firebase rules:

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {

        ...

        function isOwner(userId) {
            return request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId
        }

        function docData() {
            return resource.data;
        }

        function newDocData() {
            return request.resource.data
        }

        // Settings
        match /settings/{settingsId} {
            allow read, write: if isOwner(newDocData().userId) || isOwner(docData().userId);
        }
    }
}
```

Code that writes in the `settings` collection:

```
export async function updateSettings(userId?: string, updatedSettings?: Settings) {
    if (!updatedSettings || !userId) {
        throw new Error("Updated settings and user ID are required");
    }
    const settingsDocRef = doc(firestore, `${DB_PATH_SETTINGS}/${userId}`);
    await updateDoc(settingsDocRef, updatedSettings.toDbObject(true));
}
```

The code uses fun `toDbObject()`, which simply converts the object into:

```
{
  "id": "v26SQ...X1IrT",
  "userId": "X6yMO...aGIZR",
  "notifications": [
    {
      "type": "campaign_changed_the_status",
      "isActive": true,
      "isEnabled": false
    },
    ...
  ],
  "emails": [
    {
      "email": "example@gmail.com",
      "isMain": true
    },
    ...
  ],
  "updatedAt": {
    "seconds": 1693555820,
    "nanoseconds": 353000000
  }
}
```

The difference in data before/after I call `updateSettings()`:

[image]

Rules validation results from debugger:

[image]

[image]

Would be great to understand how to solve this issue or at least how to debug it to find the reason.

Comment: Please edit the question to show `updatedSettings.toDbObject(true))`.  That seems important to know in order to evaluate the rule, since it looks at the contents of the document.  Even better if you just hard code the value and put it inline so it's absolutely clear what you're passing. You should also show the contents of the existing document just before the function is called both times.

Comment: Not tested, by my guess is that `docData()` fails for the `create` and the rules engine doesn't short-circuit boolean evaluation.

Comment: @DougStevenson, good idea! I just added data examples and the difference between objects before/after the change.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen hmm, do you know if there is a way to verify this assumption?